# Linking web parts of documents that are linked to other documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, excel, excel-web-access-webpart

I currently have a whiteboard where I have put up documents and charts as a visual representation. I would like to digitalize this board in SharePoint, so that I can make changes in the original documents and it will be automatically updated on the digital board.

However, the Excel documents that I would like to put on the digital board are linked to several other Excel documents. When I try to link the first document as a web part, SharePoint cannot load the document, saying that there was an error because the document is linked to other documents. 
Is there a way to solve this?